# iOS Charts: Determine Circle Position on chartValueSelected()

Tags: swift, ios-charts, nspopover

I am using [iOS Charts](https://github.com/danielgindi/Charts) with Swift 3.

When a user clicks on a circle/point on my graph, I want to show a popup that has the value and a date.

[image: Graph]

I detect the click inside `chartValueSelected()` and show the popup like this:

```
func chartValueSelected(_ chartView: ChartViewBase, entry: ChartDataEntry, highlight: Highlight) {
  //Set and show the popup...
  //...
  self.presentViewController(vc, asPopoverRelativeTo: frame, of: graph, preferredEdge: .minY, behavior: .transient)
}
```

Right now I am just positioning the popup arbitrarily with `frame` because I don't know how to determine where the user clicked.

Is there a way to know the x/y coordinates of where the clicked circle is?

Answer (score 0):

Ah, found it!

The `hightlight` value returned by the delegate method has `xPx` and `yPx` properties related to where the circle is. Wow, they really thought of everything with this graph library. :)

So I hard-coded a relative offset like this:

```
let frame = CGRect(x: highlight.xPx-36, y: highlight.yPx-15, width: 73, height: 54)
```

...and it works:
[image]